# Entity with ECK: image is there, but it doesn't render properly

Tags: 7, media, entities

I've created a new entity type with [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and added an image field. All is well: I can create an entity and add the image, on the edit interface it shows up properly. However, when I display the entity, the image gives a 404 because for some reason, I end up with `<img>`s like this:

`<img src="<root of Drupal instance>" />`

Do you have any idea on how to debug / fix this?

Comment: how are you displaying the entity? with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the display provided by ECK itself.